# Rodinia File not found when "make"

Tags: cuda, makefile

I tried to run Rodinia on my computer with cuda 5.5, given the makefile provided by the rodinia suits. In the common config file, I change the directory location from /usr/local/cuda/ to /usr/local/cuda/cuda and leave everything unchanged. My nvcc works fine. However, when I type in make, i got the error

/usr/local/cuda/cuda/bin/nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/cuda/include -O2 -c backprop_cuda.cu
backprop_cuda.cu:12:35: error: backprop_cuda_kernel.cu: No such file or directory

while clearly in the directory there is a file called backprop_cuda_kernel.cu

```
backprop.c               backprop.h   facetrain.o  Makefile
backprop_cuda.cu         backprop.o   imagenet.c   Makefile_nvidia
backprop_cuda_kernel.cu  facetrain.c  imagenet.o   run
```

The make file is:

```
include ../../common/make.config

CC = gcc
CC_FLAGS = -g  -O2

NVCC = $(CUDA_DIR)/bin/nvcc
NVCC_FLAGS = -I$(CUDA_DIR)/include

ifeq ($(dbg),1)
    NVCC_FLAGS += -g -O0
else
    NVCC_FLAGS += -O2
endif

ifeq ($(emu),1)
    NVCC_FLAGS += -deviceemu
endif


backprop: backprop.o facetrain.o imagenet.o backprop_cuda.o 
$(CC) $ (CC_FLAGS) backprop.o facetrain.o imagenet.o backprop_cuda.o -o backprop -
L$(CUDA_LIB_DIT) -lcuda -lcudart -lm

%.o: %.[ch]
$(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $< -c

facetrain.o: facetrain.c backprop.h
$(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) facetrain.c -c

backprop.o: backprop.c backprop.h
$(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) backprop.c -c 

backprop_cuda.o:backprop_cuda.cu backprop.h $(NVCC) $(NVCC_FLAGS) -c backprop_cuda.cu

imagenet.o: imagenet.c backprop.h $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) imagenet.c -c

clean: rm -f *.o *~ backprop backprop_cuda.linkinfo
```

Sorry I couldn't put it in the code format, the websites keeps telling me that my indent is wrong

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about nvcc etc. but this error:

```
backprop_cuda.cu:12:35: error: backprop_cuda_kernel.cu: No such file or directory
```

implies that at line 12 of `backprop_cuda.cu` you are including a file named `backprop_cude_kernel.cu`.  You say that this file exists in your current directory.  However, the compile line you give to `nvcc` doesn't list the current directory as a place to search for included files.

If `nvcc` doesn't search the local directory by default, then you'll have to add something like `-I$(CURDIR)` to your `nvcc` line to get it to look there.

Comment: Where should I add -I$(CURDIR). in the make file listed above or in the common configuration file? I apologize in advance if this is a simple question as I am very new to this

Comment: I don't know what "common configuration file" you refer to.  I suggest adding the new `-I` flag in the same place as the current one, in the `NVCC_FLAGS` variable in the makefile.  Just remember StackOverflow is for quick answers to specific, technical questions.  It's not a place to go for a tutorial in how to write programs etc.  If you really don't know anything about these tools then you should find and read the documentation first, then if you have questions on details StackOverflow is a good place for help.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace **#include backprop_cuda_kernel.cu** present in the backprop_cuda.cu file by **#include "backprop_cuda_kernel.cu"**
The backprop_cuda_kernel.cu is present in the directory you are doing a make.